# Is there is any possible way to extract the network calls of Google Chrome Developer tools via Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to extract the Network calls from Network tab of Developer tools on Chrome,i can able to open the developer tools on chrome via (Ctrl+Shift+I) selenium webdriver.But, i could n't able to access the network tab

Is there is any specific xpath available for chrome Developer tools, to access the Network tab?

kindly do reply if possible.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of ideas:

1. Record pressing F12 in your Selenium script to open debug tools. You can then use hotkeys such as ctrl+2 while focused in the debug tools to get to the network tools view. I'm not sure how reliable this would be though since Preserve log might not be something you can default in the network tools view
2. Install and run a network monitoring tool such as Fiddler. This runs outside of Chrome and captures all inbound / outbound HTTP traffic

Comment: The hot key "Ctrl+2" not navigating to the network tab after opening developer tools. i tried manually. Is this right?

Comment: The hotkey will only work if you are focused in the devtools area, and if you enable it under your devtools preferences - General -> Appearance -> Enable Ctrl+1-9 shortcut to switch panels

Comment: Thanks..it's working manually now, will try to execute this with Webdriver

Comment: Is there is any xpath available to access the developer tools? via webdriver

Comment: Not that I know of, so option 2 - Fiddler might be the way to go

Comment: Ok..Thanks for the reply, will try with that

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you need to do it directly from Chrome. Download the Fiddler Core framework- http://www.telerik.com/fiddler/fiddlercore 
There is a nice C# API that you can integrate into your code and listen for all requests made through the test.

Comment: Actually am trying to automate web calls via selenium web driver(chrome), In order to achieve this,i need a help of accessing chrome developer tools using selenium web driver